# return an object from a function which execute a while true

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

In a very naive way I'm trying to save to a gzip file.
I add to the queue chuncks of that file in one separate thread, because gzip compression in quite expensive. The simplest solution I've found in internet to use multithread is to define a new function which reads from a queue this way:

```
def savegz(filegz, workQueue):
  while True:
    user_list = workQueue.get()
    print 'start'
    for chunck in user_list: 
      filegz.writelines(chunck)
    print 'end'
    workQueue.task_done()

...
workQueue = Queue(0)
thread1 = Thread(target=savegz, args=(filegz, workQueue))
thread1.setDaemon(True)
thread1.start()
...
for user_list in something(a):
  workQueue.put(user_list)
...
workQueue.join()
filegz.close()
```

But this way it never prints 'end'. 
I know it's not the good way to save to file, but I think the problem is I never return filegz. But I don't want to return it, because this way I quit the while True.
I've seen the yield function, but I don't think it would work.

Comment: You've set `thread1` as a daemon thread. Do you do anything to wait for its work to complete, or do you just end the program before it can finish its job?

Comment: At the very end of the file I have:
workQueue.join()
filegz.close()

Comment: You should join in thread1.

Comment: Are your program exiting without printing `end`? If that is the case, you must `join` on `thread1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `thread1` should not be daemon or you should `join` on `thread1`.

You need a way to inform `thread1` that there is no more items. You  can put a special value on the queue to indicate this:

```
def savegz(filegz, workQueue):
  while True:
    user_list = workQueue.get()
    if user_list == None:
      break
    print 'start'
    for chunck in user_list:
      filegz.writelines(chunck)
    print 'end'
    workQueue.task_done()

...
workQueue = Queue(0)
thread1 = Thread(target=savegz, args=(filegz, workQueue))
thread1.setDaemon(False)
thread1.start()
...
for user_list in something(a):
  workQueue.put(user_list)
...
workQueue.put(None)
```

Comment: ok without the Daemon argument it works. But it's WAY slower than without multitrheading.
With threads: each chunck takes 3-4sec
Without threads: 1 chunck 1 sec.
Anyway, thank you